# Get a list of Devices and access to their storage

Tags: c#, android, .net, device, amazon-fire-os

I'm currently trying to create an app in C# that will sync items between a PC and connected device.

The device will be an Amazon Fire 8 and I was wondering if it is possible to get the device info, such as Android ID, and also get access to the storage on the tablet itself?

Comment: Hi All, just to give a reply on what I used for this. I used WPD to get a list of all the MTP devices attached. From here I created a list of all the devices and then iterated through the contents. Thanks to the tuts from CGeers :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give a reply on what I used for this. I used WPD to get a list of all the MTP devices attached. From here I created a list of all the devices and then iterated through the contents.
Thanks to the tuts from CGeers :D